# Webcomic about adventures of a group of low-end superheroes

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I've read this webcomic a few years ago, up to about halfway through its run at the time, and wasn't able to find it again (despite actively looking several times).

What I remember is that the main characters were a bunch of E-list superheroes, so weak/obscure that they were basically shut out of most superheroing jobs and had to get some jobs wherever (not necessarily related to their powers).

At one point one of the protagonists accepted a job in a 80s comic book store, which sold 80s comic books, and paid 80s wages (i.e. something like $2 per hour), but that was still the best job offer she could find at the time.
At some later point an extensive arc covered the adventures of one of the other protagonists across a bunch of assorted alien bases on Mars. I don't recall how he ended up on Mars. The whole thing was pretty weird.

I probably originally found it on TV Tropes (or, at least, I recall it having a page there), but while searching for it later I checked literally the entire TV Tropes list of webcomics, and couldn't find it. (But maybe I just missed it, or the page was deleted.)
It had some witty name, as webcomics tend to, but I don't currently recall anything specific about that name.
Any idea what it could have been?

(Note: I'm almost sure that all of the above was a single webcomic, but it is, in principle, possible that those scenes come from different comics that my memory combined. I hope that didn't happen.)